# Why is there a large memory increment at function definition line?

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I am running into memory limits and have used the magic memory_profiler to look into the function with the largest increment.

I can see that almost all the memory increment occurs in the function definition line:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents

60        6141.9 MiB   4376.1 MiB  def quantiles(ticks, lb, quantile_entry, quantile_exit=0,
61                                           quantile_period='1D'):  
62        6141.9 MiB   0.0 MiB         quantile_entry = int(quantile_entry * 10)
...
118       6134.1 MiB   0.0 MiB         return ticks
```

I am guessing this is because the function is creating copies of the arguments it receives?

Input dataframe 'ticks' can become quite big, but even then I would only expect the increment to be a maximum of ~100% of the prior usage. Here it jumps from ~2GB --> ~6GB.  Any suggestions how to better understand this increase?

Comment: Function calls themselves aren't going to be allocating memory, since the arguments will be passed by reference. The increment column is just the change in memory usage since the last time it was checked. Do you have instrumentation in other functions that might allocate?

Answer (score 0):

Python's behavior is passing by value just when you handle immutable parameters. That said if you pass a *mutable object* (like a `DataFrame`) it is *passed by reference*: if something is cloning the dataframe has to be done *explicitly inside* the function by any instruction.

My guess is that in the code, that you didn't share, between line `62` and `118` something is expanding `ticks` variable. My suggestion is to take into consideration also constants when you do calculation:

if you have

```
l = [1] * (1e6)
```

and inside a function you do something like

```
def my_function(li):
    for i in range(len(li)): # O(n) loop
        li.append([1,2])
    return li
```

it's true that the space-complexity is `O(n)` however I'm expecting to have the constant multiplying the memory will be higher than `2` (or ~100% you mentioned); in this case I'm expecting:

```
mem(my_function(l)) > 3 * mem(l)
```